# How to replace some rows in a dataframe with the corresponding rows from other data frame with additional columns

Tags: python, pandas

Let's assume I have two dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2, 3],
                   'B': [300, 400, 500, 600], 
                   'C': [6, 7, 8, 9]})
df1.set_index('A', inplace=True)
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2, 3],
                    'B': [433, 555],
                    'C': [99, 99],
                    'D': [1, 2]})
df2.set_index('A', inplace=True)
```

I want to replace rows in `df1` with rows in `df2` based on index. My first attempts were:

```
df1.update(df2)
df1.loc[df2.index, :] = df2
```

However, it only replaces columns that excisted in `df1` and doesn't add `D` column from `df2`. How can I add `D` column as well with `NaN` values for other rows?

Please note that my original data frames have hundreds of columns, and original `df2` have many additional columns so any manual definitions of columns to be used/created will be enormously cumbersome.

Comment: Is possible create some sample data with expected output (with more columns, rows)? Because not easy testing answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Let's use [`pd.DataFrame.combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
df2.combine_first(df1)
```

Output:

```
       B     C    D
A                  
0  300.0   6.0  NaN
1  400.0   7.0  NaN
2  433.0  99.0  1.0
3  555.0  99.0  2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the combine function as follows.

```
df_new = df1.combine(df2, func=lambda s1, s2: s2.fillna(s1))
```

This is very similar to the combine_first method mentioned in a previous answer but gives you a bit more freedom as you can write the function you want to apply yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [`DataFrame.align`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.align.html) with [`DataFrame.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'B': [300, 400, 500, 600], 'E': [6, 7, 8, 9]}) 
df1.set_index('A', inplace=True) 
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2, 5], 'B': [433, 555], 'C': [99, 99], 'D': [1, 2]}) 
df2.set_index('A', inplace=True)
print (df1)
     B  E
A        
0  300  6
1  400  7
2  500  8
3  600  9

print (df2)
     B   C  D
A            
2  433  99  1
5  555  99  2
```

---

```
df1, df2 = df1.align(df2)
print (df1)
       B   C   D    E
A                    
0  300.0 NaN NaN  6.0
1  400.0 NaN NaN  7.0
2  500.0 NaN NaN  8.0
3  600.0 NaN NaN  9.0
5    NaN NaN NaN  NaN

print (df2)
       B     C    D   E
A                      
0    NaN   NaN  NaN NaN
1    NaN   NaN  NaN NaN
2  433.0  99.0  1.0 NaN
3    NaN   NaN  NaN NaN
5  555.0  99.0  2.0 NaN
```

---

```
df1.update(df2)
print (df1)
       B     C    D    E
A                       
0  300.0   NaN  NaN  6.0
1  400.0   NaN  NaN  7.0
2  433.0  99.0  1.0  8.0
3  600.0   NaN  NaN  9.0
5  555.0  99.0  2.0  NaN
```

EDIT: Because sorting problem is possible change `align` to [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by [`Index.union`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.union.html) of columns and if necessary also by indexes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'E': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'A': [300, 400, 500, 600], 'C': [6, 7, 8, 9]}) 
df1.set_index('A', inplace=True) 
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2, 5], 'C': [433, 555], 'B': [99, 99], 'D': [1, 2]}) 
df2.set_index('A', inplace=True)

idx = df1.index.union(df2.index, sort=False)
cols = df1.columns.union(df2.columns, sort=False) 
df1 = df1.reindex(index=idx,columns=cols) 
df2 = df2.reindex(index=idx,columns=cols) 
print (df1)
       E    C   B   D
A                    
300  0.0  6.0 NaN NaN
400  1.0  7.0 NaN NaN
500  2.0  8.0 NaN NaN
600  3.0  9.0 NaN NaN
2    NaN  NaN NaN NaN
5    NaN  NaN NaN NaN

print (df2)
      E      C     B    D
A                        
300 NaN    NaN   NaN  NaN
400 NaN    NaN   NaN  NaN
500 NaN    NaN   NaN  NaN
600 NaN    NaN   NaN  NaN
2   NaN  433.0  99.0  1.0
5   NaN  555.0  99.0  2.0
```

---

```
df1.update(df2)
print (df1)
       E      C     B    D
A                         
300  0.0    6.0   NaN  NaN
400  1.0    7.0   NaN  NaN
500  2.0    8.0   NaN  NaN
600  3.0    9.0   NaN  NaN
2    NaN  433.0  99.0  1.0
5    NaN  555.0  99.0  2.0
```

Comment: The `df1.align(df2)` seems to sort columns alphabetically. How can I preserve the orginal order of columns?

Comment: Unfortunetely, the `df1.update(df2)` results in `TypeError: invalid type promotion` on my original DataFrame.

Comment: @jakes - Hard question, it seems data related problem. What is your pandas version?

Comment: My pandas is 1.0.1

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
df1.update(df2)

cols = df2.columns[~ df2.columns.isin(df1.columns)]
mask = df2.index.isin(df1.index)
df1[cols] = df2[cols][mask]

df1
```

output:

[image]

---

without `pandas.DataFrame.update`:

```
df1_mask_index = df1.index.isin(df2.index)
df2_mask_index = df2.index.isin(df1.index)

same_cols = df1.columns[df1.columns.isin(df2.columns)]
diff_cols = df2.columns[~df2.columns.isin(df1.columns)]

df1[df1_mask_index] = df2[same_cols][df2_mask_index]
df1[diff_cols] = df2[diff_cols][df2_mask_index]

df1
```

output:

[image]